# What's up with the pink sausages and onions?

Tags: overwatch

One of the many sprays available in-game shows a pink sausage holding a leek, and is commonly seen with his turnip-onion baby, seen here:

[image]

[image]

All of the sprays in game, for every hero either references something that can be attributed to that hero or references another part of Blizzard's story.  For example, there is a boy spray that shows a young kid with his arm in a cast out, and this references the Overwatch museum cinematic.

However, I swear I've seen this before somewhere but this pink sausage is driving me nuts.  What reference is Blizzard making with this and the onion baby?

Comment: Pretty sure it's a turnip named is Pachimari, and a karate hot dog holding celery, and I'm 95% sure they aren't references to other things.

Comment: I'm calling it now, the 25th hero will be a pink sausage that shoots onion babies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may look familiar for a few reasons-

It is elsewhere in the game, such as the arcade in Hanamura:
[image]

And these characters are inspired by Taiko no Tatsujin:
[image]

Comment: What makes you say that the characters are inspired by whatever that is?

Comment: The curvature at the top of the characters mouths and harrowing black eyes look pretty similar

Answer (score 4):

The "turnip-onion baby" is called Pachimari:

[image: Pachimari Spray]

Where as the "pink sausage holding a leek" seems to be as yet unnamed but from the same in-game show/universe as Pachimari.

As you noticed Pachimari shows up in various locations throughout the game including [movie posters in Hollywood during events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV8Jf.png), [the Arcade in Hanamura](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSkBl.jpg), and various event and non event sprays and [Player icons](https://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Player_Icons).

Not much is known about Pachimari thus far, though it is thought to be either a "[Half-Onion Half Octopus](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Pachimari)" (Note the suckers on the green tentacles), or a "[part Turnip part Octopus](https://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Pachimari)". It appears to be used by Blizzard as an extra flavour for part of world building. So far seems to not play any real importance in Hero Lore (with the exception of a certain Hog taking a shine to the stuffy [see below]),
but it has made its way [into other Blizzard games](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvErF.jpg).

[image]

Comment: Not really sure this is answering the question - you don't explain what (if any) references are being made, just the in-game lore of the symbols.

Comment: @MageXy, was trying to answer this part of the question "All of the sprays in game, for every hero either references something that can be attributed to that hero or references another part of Blizzard's story." Pachimari isn't referencing anything external, it is just part of the Overwatch world. Whereas the Punch Kid (in OP's example) in the cinematic is the original source referenced by the sprays, the Pachimari sprays and stuffy toys in the answer are the original sources (not references).

Answer (score -3):

Yeah, the Pachimari turnip-squid plushie UFO-catcher prizes in the Hanamura arcade are most likely a reference to the smiling doe-eyed drum characters from "Taiko no Tatsujin", which is a popular drum peripheral game by Namco playable at Japanese arcades.  Based on the fact that the visual style for the cute character faces being exactly the same and both Pachimari and Taiko being Japanese arcade games, I think it's a pretty clear if not overt inspiration.  Overwatch has plenty of homages throughout its different media so I wouldn't be surprised.

Comment: Your answer is not adding anything that the accepted answer doesn't already mention.